# Matlab: Easy way of getting the standard basis vectors?

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

It seems like this should be easy, but I'm no expert and google isn't helping.

I would like an elegant way in Matlab of producing the standard ordered basis vectors for an n-dimensional space. For example, behaviour similar to the following:

```
>> [e1, e2] = SOB(2);
>> e1

  e1 =    1     0

>> e2

  e2 =    0     1
```

I'm *hoping* for a 1-liner and don't really want to write a function for something so simple.

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Why not

```
A = eye(N);
```

then `A(:,i)` is your i-th basis vector

Answer (score 8):

To obtain a *single* basis vector, say the `k`-th standard basis vector in `N` dimensions, you can use:

```
yourbasisvector = double(1:N == k)
```

`1:N` produces the vector `1 2 ... N`, which `== k` element-wise tests for equality with `k`; `double` converts the logical values to numbers.

Comment: This is amazing. I've been trying to either come up with, or find, a solution like this one for weeks. You can even extend this approach by doing `double(1:N == [k1, k2, k3]')` to get multiple identity vectors at once.

Answer (score 5):

Would two lines be ok? Create the identity matrix with [EYE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/eye.html), copy vectors into a cell array using [MAT2CELL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mat2cell.html), then distribute them with [DEAL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/deal.html).

```
tmp = mat2cell(eye(N),N,ones(N,1));
[e1,e2,...,eN] = deal(tmp{:})
```

Comment: 2 lines could work... Though (to me) that is rather cryptic :)

Comment: @des4maisons: I have edited a bit to clarify. Basically, if you combine basis vectors into an array, you get the identity. So I construct the identity matrix and take it apart.

Comment: Yah, I figured that was the way to do it, I just didn't know how, so thanks. Also, did you mean to link to mat2cell, or use num2cell?

Comment: @des4maisons: oops, it should be mat2cell. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

if you anonymous function, it is more convenient.

```
e = @(x) eye(size(A))(:,x);
```

If the size of A is 6 by 6, this returns 6 by 1 vector.

```
e(1) = [1;0;0;0;0;0]
```

Comment: ``Error: ()-indexing must appear last in an index expression.``

Comment: @User1291 Did you defined matrix `A`?

Comment: doesn't matter. I already get that error if I hardcode the size (e.g. ``eye(5)(:,3)``)