# How to get a standard basis vector in Julia?

Tags: julia, linear-algebra, memory-efficient

What is the most readable and efficient way to write a standard basis vector

```
e_1 = [1,0,...,0]
...
e_n = [0,...,0,1]
```

in Julia? (Similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32841880/one-line-standard-basis-vector-creation) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754929/matlab-easy-way-of-getting-the-standard-basis-vectors) matlab question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The existing answers produce an `Array{Bool}` or a `BitArray`. Depending on what you're doing, you may also be interested in [OneHotArrays.jl](https://github.com/FluxML/OneHotArrays.jl):

```
julia> (1:3) .== 2
3-element BitVector:
 0
 1
 0

julia> using LinearAlgebra

julia> I[1:3, 2]
3-element Vector{Bool}:
 0
 1
 0

julia> using OneHotArrays

julia> onehot(2, 1:3)
3-element OneHotVector(::UInt32) with eltype Bool:
 ⋅
 1
 ⋅

julia> dump(ans)
OneHotVector{UInt32}
  indices: UInt32 0x00000002
  nlabels: Int64 3
```

Comment: `OneHotVector(2,3)` is perhaps cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

The most readable version I found to write standard basis vector `e_k` was

```
using LinearAlgebra: I

I[1:n, k]
```

How this works: The identity is of type Uniform Scaling [`I = LinearAlgebra.UniformScaling(1.)`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/#LinearAlgebra.UniformScaling) which means it acts as a (dimensionless) abstract matrix (but is not allocated). We can therefore index into it to get a standard basis vector.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is:

```
e(n, k) = (1:n) .== k
```